# Recover the value of onchange in php

Tags: javascript, onchange

I recover the value of the users click in my dropdown list like that :

```
       <select onChange="document.getElementById('selectValue').value=this.value;document.getElementById('selectedValue').innerHTML=this.value;">
```

I would like compare the value that the uses click  with all values present in my database. For that
I did a foreach in php  like it : ( ofc I wrote my request above for persons3)

```
if (!empty($_POST["ingred"]) AND (!empty($_POST["quanti"]))){
$var_ingred = $_POST["ingred"];
$var_quanti = $_POST['quanti'];
foreach($persons3 as $ET3){
    #echo ($ET3['id_ingredient']);
    #echo $_POST["ingred"];
    if(($ET3['id_ingredient']) ==  onChange="document.getElementById('selectValue').value=this.value;document.getElementById('selectedValue').innerHTML=this.value){
    $condition = 1;}
    else{
    $condition = 0;}
```

But It doesn't work,   I would like know what can I do to recover the value of onchange and  compare it with $ET3['id_ingredient']

Thanks !

Comment: This is actually a javascript question. I would research ajax as that will point you to the correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

you have mix php with js code.
php run on server. So can't understand about the:

```
==  onChange="document.getElementById('selectValue')
```

You have to write an ajax request to php script passing the user's selection value.

Comment: Thanks !  But I have no idea how to do it with ajax

Comment: So you have to read https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp